# What is a single-word synonym for "hobbyist writer"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am trying to find a single-word synonym for **hobbyist writer**. Any answers please.

Comment: "Amateur" perhaps.

Comment: Some context and research would help you to get useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

By analogy with *[bibliophile](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/bibliophile)* (*one who loves books*), you can use *scribophile* (*one who loves writing*).

(There's even an [online writing group](http://www.scribophile.com/) by that name.)

If by "hobbyist" you imply "[*amateur*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/amateur)" (in the sense of '*someone who does not do something very well*' rather than '*someone who does something because they enjoy it instead of as a job*'), then the somewhat less complimentary terms *scribbler* or *hack* come to mind.